# Getting NullPointerException error while performing fit

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, pyspark

I am working on PySpark code to calculate the closest cluster, and I am getting NullPointerException error while performing fit.

This is working fine when I read data from the database into df1 and pass that df1 directly to the vector assembler.

I have updated code to read data from JSON and loaded data into spark data Frame df2, I've done split on df2 to create two new columns from one column and join on df1 using those two columns.

Now I have all data I need in df1 and I did ceil to calculate one more new column in df1. Then I am passing df1 to vector assembler for calculating closest cluster where I am seeing the NullPointerException error.

I have tried all possible solutions I have known like fillna(), count for rows that has null or null values, but data seems to be correct and not found any null values. Please advise.

```
jsonFile = requests.get(f"{args['api_url']}")
dataJson = json.loads(jsonFile.text)
dataList = []

for item in dataJson:
    dataList.append([item['subCd'], item['totalSeats']])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=dataList,schema=['subCd', 'totalSeats'])
```

df2 looks like below:

```
         subCd        totalSeats
         00 100         89
         00 111         89
         00 141         80
```

df1 looks like below:

```
|date|number|equip|code|flt|body|hours|

2022-04-01|7898|100|00|45D|R|0.7000|
2022-04-01|4567|ASE|SE|46E|R|0.5000|
2022-04-01|3265|141|00|47K|R|0.6000|
```

```
df2 = df2.select(F.col('totalSeats'), F.split(F.col('subCd'), " ").getItem(0).alias('code'),
                                 F.split(F.col('subCd'), " ").getItem(1).alias('equip')).drop('subCd')

# Determine total seats
df1 = df1.alias('prim_df').join(
            df2.alias('sec_df'),
            [
                F.col('prim_df.code')  == F.col('sec_df.code'),
                F.col('prim_df.equip') == F.col('sec_df.equip'),
            ],
            'inner'
            ).select(
                F.col('prim_df.*'),
                F.col('sec_df.totalSeats')
            )

df1 = df1.select(F.col('*'), F.concat(F.col('body'), F.ceil(F.col('totalSeats')/F.lit(50)) * F.lit(50)).alias('body_seat_group')).drop('totalSeats')
```

This produced df1 as expected, like below:

```
|date|number|equip|code|flt|body|hours|body_seat_group|

2022-04-01|7898|100|00|45D|R|0.7000|R100
2022-04-01|3265|141|00|47K|R|0.6000|R100
```

```
vecAssembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols =["hours"], outputCol = "features", handleInvalid='skip')
new_data = vecAssembler.transform(df1)

scale = StandardScaler(inputCol='features', outputCol='standardized')
data_scale = scale.fit(new_data)
data_scale_output=data_scale.transform(new_data)

kmeans = KMeans(k=6, seed=1)
model = kmeans.fit(new_data.select('features'))
```

It fails at the code `(kmeans.fit(new_data.select('features'))`.

Error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o251.fit.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 11 in stage 57.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 11.3 in stage 57.0 (TID 703) (10.32.220.213 executor 2): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.unsafe.sort.UnsafeExternalSorter.getSortedIterator(UnsafeExternalSorter.java:517)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.UnsafeExternalRowSorter.sort(UnsafeExternalRowSorter.java:172)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage5.findNextInnerJoinRows$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage5.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$2.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:774)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anon$3.hasNext(RDD.scala:951)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:454)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.$anonfun$doPutIterator$1(BlockManager.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManager$$doPut(BlockManager.scala:1350)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1414)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:1237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:384)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Comment: *** Update - This is working fine when I write the JSON data to DB and read it from DB to Pyspark DataFrame. I am tickling my head around this knowing the fact that JSON is messing up some format but not sure what exactly it is.